# How to show fragment with data again when view is swiped back to in Viewpager having a tab layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to read RSS feed and show the content of it in card view which is inside ViewPager with tab layout. It shows fragment with data initially, but when swiped back from another tab, the whole card layout with data,disappears.

Comment: what si the offScreenPageLimt() you set to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to handle the same situation. I had TabLayout in ViewPager.

I have used FragmentPagerAdapter with off screen page limit set to (NO_OF_TABS - 1). This is to hold all the fragments in memory and they wont be destroyed and recreated as you swipe back and forth. As my fragments are small in size meaning not many views every fragment has so it was okay for me. But this way fragments always holds the latest data. Say, if user had entered text in EditText and swipe to end and come back, then fragment will still have the text that user had entered.

In your case, if you have not set the page limit the default is 1 so the fragment gets destroyed when you swipe away so you lose the data.

IN ADDITION TO ABOVE:
If you can not keep all fragments in memory, you may consider using FragmentStatePagerAdapter. This adapter saves the states of fragments that are being destroyed and it will use the same state to represent in fragment when user swipe back to this fragment. But there are issues around StaePagerAdapter while it destroys adn recreate the fragments, there are indexing issues so you will easily get IndexOutOfBoundException if you swipe. This is with page screen limit set to less than the total fragments.

Comment: I'm using a StatePagerAdapter, so if I set page screen limit equal to total fragments, then would i get IndexoutOfBoundException?

Comment: you wont get in that case as there is no chance of destroying.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. One more thing, I am fetching RSS data for each fragment everytime the views are swiped to. Is there anyway to load data only once and show that?

Comment: Add the fetching code in onViewCreated (). Add it loads fragment when the adapter is set onViewCreated of all fragments will also be called then. So if fetching data doesn't take so much time,  the data will be ready for you by the time your start swiping.

Comment: Handle the case if the data is not ready to avoid crashes all that. .

Comment: If it's not so big data you can store data in serialised form...or see if sqlite will help you. .

Comment: The fetching code is an asynctask. What can I do to wait for it to complete? I know about onpostexecute but I cant use that for fragments in my code. Any other way to wait for asynck task to complete?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98467/discussion-between-cgr-and-aman-b).